# TinyMce keeps adding inline style tags, how to disable them

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, styling

I am trying to style content with "tinymce": "^5.10.5"

I've added my own CSS file as described in https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles.

But the content keep coming out with span tags that have their own CSS, overwriting my custom css

```
<span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: #ffffff;">
```

This is my initialization declaration

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '#section-' + sectionIdentifier + ' textarea',
        content_css: "/build/app.css",
        plugins: ["lists", "table", "code"],
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | code removeformat |',
        branding: false,
    });
```

How can i set my own font here without inline styling overwriting my css

Comment: How do you expect the editor to output the selected font size, then?

Comment: My main issue is that the font-family is overwritten. Setting font-size, bold is fine, but i'd like to set my own font

Comment: Then you have to disable the font family picker in the editor.

Comment: There is no font family picker in the toolbar declaration. Removing it doesnt change style attribute

Comment: Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle with your configuration that demonstrates this in action? You can create and fork your example here:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/